# SQL - how to filter for PRODUCT_AGE less than 12 in this query. My example returns an error

Tags: sql, reference, aggregate, outer-join, having-clause

I am trying to get products groups that have products with a PRODUCT_AGE less than 12 months old.

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT MIN(SHIP_TABLE.SHIPDATE) FIRST_SHIPPED, PRODUCT_TABLE.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID, 
DATEDIFF(MONTH,MIN(SHIP_TABLE.SHIPDATE),GETDATE()) PRODUCT_AGE 
FROM SHIP_TABLE 
LEFT JOIN PRODUCT_TABLE ON PRODUCT_TABLE.PRODUCT_ID = SHIP_TABLE.PRODUCT_ID
WHERE SHIP_TABLE.PRODUCT_ID BETWEEN '101000000' and '999999999' AND 
PRODUCT_TABLE.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID IS NOT NULL AND 
DATEDIFF(MONTH, MIN(SHIP_TABLE.SHIPDATE),GETDATE()) <= 12 
GROUP BY PRODUCT_TABLE.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID 
ORDER BY PRODUCT_TABLE.PRODUCT_GROUP_ID ASC
```

This query returns an aggregate error.

I've tried using a subquery; but, couldn't get it to work either.

The SHIP_TABLE lists the dates of all products; while, the PRODUCT_TABLE lists the Products and their product groups.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get my query to properly filter?

Comment: What have you tried? Also, that wall of text is very hard to read. You need to make it easily to read and comprehend.

Comment: the query works without the needed filter - DATEDIFF(MONTH, MIN(SHIP_TABLE.SHIPDATE),GETDATE()) <= 12, i tried creating a subquery, but couldnt get it to work either.  I am trying to get the first shipped date from a list of products that are part of a product group.  There are 2 tables Ship_Table which lists the ship dates of all products and a 2nd table Product_Table which list the products and there associated product groups.

Comment: Correction, i already have the first shipped date by product group id, i trying to filter for only the product groups that have products that have a first shipped date less than 12 months old.  When i add the filter, this query returns and aggregate error

Comment: When you have `MIN(SHIP_TABLE.SHIPDATE) FIRST_SHIPPED`, are you trying to create an alias. So that the result of `MIN(SHIP_TABLE.SHIPDATE)` will have a column name of `FIRST_SHIPPED`?

Comment: Please **describe the observed behavior** (including any exact error message) and how that differs from **the expected behavior**. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a **specific problem or error** and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have `MIN(SHIP_TABLE.SHIPDATE) FIRST_SHIPPED` and `DATEDIFF(MONTH,MIN(SHIP_TABLE.SHIPDATE),GETDATE()) PRODUCT_AGE`, I believe you are trying to use aliases. This is incorrect syntax. Aliases are used with the `as` keyword:

```
MIN(SHIP_TABLE.SHIPDATE) AS FIRST_SHIPPED
DATEDIFF(MONTH,MIN(SHIP_TABLE.SHIPDATE),GETDATE()) AS PRODUCT_AGE
```

In your where-clause you have:

```
DATEDIFF(MONTH,  MIN(SHIP_TABLE.SHIPDATE),GETDATE()) <= 12
```

I believe this will cause an error; probably, your aggregate error. You should use a having clause. See [this](http://DATEDIFF(MONTH,%20%20MIN(SHIP_TABLE.SHIPDATE),GETDATE())%20%3C=%2012) post for more information.

Comment: thanks, the Having Clause was the issue